# Android – multiple custom versions of the same app

Tags: android, automation

Whats the best way to deploy several customized versions of a Android application?

Currently I have a script to exchange the resource folder for getting a customized version of my app. It works great, but all custom versions still have the same package name in the AndroidManifest.xml. Therefore it is not possible to install two customized versions of the app at the same time.

[This is one solution for this problem, but that has to be done by hand](http://droidin.net/2009/05/13/android-multiapp/)

Can you think of a more easy solution, or how this could be built into a skript?

(btw: it is not for a porn/spam/whatever app, not even a paid one)

Comment: I have answered similar question here, maybe it can help you too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840127/how-to-install-the-same-app-twice-without-interference/21332803#21332803

Comment: The accepted answer is a bit dated.  There is one posted by craned that is likely the now correct way of doing it.

Comment: You **definitely** want use [`Gradle` flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) that comes natively, encouraged even, on Android Studio.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps the built-in Android "library" concept was not fully baked at the time of the original post, but it may be the preferred method as of 2011.  Follow these steps for an ant build:

Starting from a working app (let's call it directory "myOrigApp", package com.foo.myapp), just add this line to "default.properties" to make it a library:

```
android.library=true
```

Now create a new app in a sibling directory in any way you prefer (let's call it directory "sibling", package com.foo.myVariant).  Using Intellij Idea, for example, create a project 'from scratch' with directory 'sibling' and it will create all the files/directories you would normally need.

In that new, sibling directory edit "default.properties" to add the dependency:

```
android.library.reference.1=../myOrigApp
```

Copy over the Manifest from the original dir:

```
cd sibling
cp ../myOrigApp/AndroidManifest.xml  ../myOrigApp/local.properties ../myOrigApp/build.properties  .
```

Edit that copied Manifest file to change its package name to your new variant, "com.foo.myVarient"; that's the only change.

If you just run the ant build scripts, you may be done. (I had to just set up signing keys.)

If you want to set up an IDE like Idea to have the library project as a dependent of the variant project, follow these steps to add a library project to the variant project (assumes you already have a project set up for both):

- Open the original project, bring up Project Settings, select your Facet and check "Is Library Project" and save.
- Open the variant project, bring up Project Settings, select Modules
- Add a module
- Select “Import existing module”
- Browse to the Original directory (myOrigApp) and select its .iml file (IntelliJ project source file)
- Click "Finish." (The library project is added as a module within the variant project.)
- In the modules list click over the Variant project to select it.
- On the right hand side select the "Dependencies" tab.
- Click "Add…"
- Choose "Module dependency…" (A list should appear that includes the name of the module/library you previously added to the project--perhaps the only entry in the list).
- Select the library project you added and press OK. (It will be added to the list of dependencies of your project.)
- Press OK to finish configuring the project. (You should see 2 modules, with the library's resources and classes available and recognized in the Variant project.)

Comment: credit to http://soledadpenades.com/2011/06/17/android-library-projects-with-intellij-idea/ for the Idea steps

Comment: I believe this solution didn't exist back at the time, but it is definitly better than going through sourcefiles with regular expressions. I have been using the solution of Prashast before and it did work well. But for new projects I favor the library project.

Comment: I like this solution waaaay better than altering dozens of source files (a source control nightmare!).

Comment: I believe this approach has a MAJOR limitation, in that if you use assets or some other types (?) of resources in your main application, when you turn it into a jar library, they will not be available to the spinoff version that tries to use the library.  If you're just wanting to share code and/or layouts, no problem.  But, if your app uses assets, then I think this breaks down (without some custom aapt build scripting).

Comment: You are correct @Nate.  From the doc:
The tools do not support the use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in a library project. Any asset resources used by an application must be stored in the assets/ directory of the application project itself.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html

Comment: This doesn't work. I get UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/facebook/android/R$layout; when building the silbling project. It's because it tries to make R class, I guess, and the library project also has R. If I clean the library (this removes R) I get lot of syntax errors in the project and can't use it as a library anymore.

Answer (score 6):

What I did for something similar to this is to just use an antlib task and then go through all java and xml files to replace my old package string to the new package string. It didn't matter if the files were not in the correct src paths according to the package. Just doing a regex replace for all the files was enough for me to get this working...

For example to replace it in all your java files under the src directory:

```
 <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
    <regexp pattern="old.package.string" /> 
    <substitution expression="new.package.string" />
    <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" /> 
 </replaceregexp>
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.
I am now using two replaceregexp. One is exactly as yours and another one for replacing the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, because all the source files are still in a directory structure matching the old package name. How did you solve this?

Comment: For me the source file location didn't matter. As long as they have the correct package information.

Opening it in Eclipse may not work though. I had used this only with the ant build and the use the generated apk file.

Comment: @Prashast I tried it, (1) create build.xml (2) put the <replaceregexp> but no success. Would you share a complete build.xml of a example android app? Regards...

Answer (score 6):

You **definitely** want to use [`Gradle` flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) that comes natively, encouraged even, on Android Studio.

It seems to explain all the basics really well. I just finished converting to `Gradle` today, and it works great. Custom app icons, names, and strings, etc.

As the website explains, part of the purpose behind this design was to make it more dynamic and more easily allow multiple APKs to be created with essentially the same code, which sounds similar what you're doing.

I probably didn't explain it the best, but that website does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 4):

The linked-to solution does not have to be done by hand. Bear in mind that the `package` attribute in the `<manifest>` element does not have to be where the code resides, so long as you spell out the fully-qualified classes elsewhere in the manifest (e.g., `activity android:name="com.commonsware.android.MyActivity"` rather than `activity android:name=".MyActivity"`). Script your manifest change and use Ant to build a new APK. AFAIK, that should work.

Comment: This destroys the auto-generated R file. So you have to go through more or less all your source files and change the import of the R file (point 8).

Comment: We solved the R issue.
import old.package.string.*;
import new.package.string.*;
This just imports R for both builds.

Answer (score 2):

Support Multiple Partners 
Prepare config.xml

Build project for different partner

```
<!--partner.dir, pkg.name, ver.code, ver.name are input from command line when execute 'ant' -->

<!-- set global properties for this build -->
<property name="build.bin" location="bin"/>
<property name="build.gen" location="gen"/>
<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="res" location="res"/>

<target name="preparefiles" description="Prepare files for different partner" >
    <delete dir="${build.bin}" />
    <delete dir="${build.gen}" />

    <copy todir="${res}" overwrite="true" />
        <fileset dir="${partner.dir}/res" /> 
    </copy>

    <!-- change the import in all Java source files -->
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match='android.versionCode="(.*)"'
        replace='android.versionCode="${ver.code}"'
        byline="false">

    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match='android.versionName="(.*)"'
        replace='android.versionName="${ver.name}"'
        byline="false">

    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml"
        match='package="(.*)"'
        replace='package="${pkg.name}"'
        byline="false">

    <!-- change the package name in AndroidManifest -->
    <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
        <regexp pattern="import(.*)com.myproject.com.R;" /> 
        <substitution expression="import com.${pkg.name}.R;" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" /> 
    </replaceregexp>

    <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
        <regexp pattern="(package com.myproject.com;)" /> 
        <substitution expression="\1&#10;import com.${pkg.name}.R;" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" /> 
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

Prepare Files
$ ant -f config.xml -Dpartner.dir="xxx" -Dpkg.name="xxx" -Dver.code="xxx" -Dver.name="xxx" preparefiles

Create build.xml
Build
$ ant debug
or
$ ant release

Comment: this is good if u work with ant only.
if you work in eclipse, after running the regexp u can work, but if you change a resource u'll be stuck again.

Comment: The file had some minor issues but all in all a good idea!  I copied this and modified it somewhat for usage in a client project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm [using the maven-android-plugin](http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/56b2449756fd4a40) to achieve this. Specify one AndroidManifest.xml for the generated-sources goal and another AndroidManifest.xml for the final apk goal. That way the source code project retains the actual source code package name during generation of the R class and the build phase, while the market adapted manifest package name is in the second AndroidManifest.xml which is included in the final apk file.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up with a script that patches the sources; patching the source sounds risky, but in presence of version control the risk is acceptable.

So I made one version, committed the source, made the other version, committed the source, and looking at diffs wrote a patching script in Python.

I am not sure if it is the best solution. (And the code misses some os.path.joins)

The heart of the script is the following function:

```
# In the file 'fname',
# find the text matching "before oldtext after" (all occurrences) and
# replace 'oldtext' with 'newtext' (all occurrences).
# If 'mandatory' is true, raise an exception if no replacements were made.
def fileReplace(fname,before,newtext,after,mandatory=True):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    pattern = r"("+re.escape(before)+r")\w+("+re.escape(after)+r")"
    replacement = r"\1"+newtext+r"\2"
    new_data,replacements_made = re.subn(pattern,replacement,read_data,flags=re.MULTILINE)
    if replacements_made and really:
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(new_data)
        if verbose:
            print "patching ",fname," (",replacements_made," occurrence", "s" if 1!=replacements_made else "",")"
    elif replacements_made:
        print fname,":"
        print new_data
    elif mandatory:
        raise Exception("cannot patch the file: "+fname)
```

And you may find the following one of use:

```
# Change the application resource package name everywhere in the src/ tree.
# Yes, this changes the java files. We hope that if something goes wrong,
# the version control will save us.
def patchResourcePackageNameInSrc(pname):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('src'):
    if '.svn' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('.svn')
    for fname in files:
        fileReplace(os.path.join(root,fname),"import com.xyz.",pname,".R;",mandatory=False)
```

There is also a function that copies assets from `x-assets-cfgname` to `assets` (earlier it turned out that for me it is more convenient to have a subdirectory in `assets`).

```
def copyAssets(vname,force=False):
    assets_source = "x-assets-"+vname+"/xxx"
    assets_target = "assets/xxx"
    if not os.path.exists(assets_source):
        raise Exception("Invalid variant name: "+vname+" (the assets directory "+assets_source+" does not exist)")
    if os.path.exists(assets_target+"/.svn"):
        raise Exception("The assets directory must not be under version control! "+assets_target+"/.svn exists!")
    if os.path.exists(assets_target):
        shutil.rmtree(assets_target)
    shutil.copytree(assets_source, assets_target, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('.svn'))
```

Well, you get the idea. Now you can write your own script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a new project and copy the stuff. steps,
- create new android project without a class
- create package (package name should be corresponding to the one in the manifest file), or just copy the package name in the 'gen' folder
- copy the java files
- copy the drawable folders
- copy the layout files
- copy any other file(s) used in ur project
- copy manifest file's data

this has been simpler for me for the task