# How to add images form remote server to android phone application

Tags: android, android-image

I am developing an android game, in which i have some trains moving on track. In this game,  i want to provide option to add some more special trains when user acquired 
a certain number of points.
But am not getting how can i do it, while in project development am putting trains images in drawable folder,
and using them as resources in my code.
Now i want to put these new trains images on to server, and if user scored some certain score than only give him option to purchase new trains using those score.
but how can i update  .apk file for these new trains for that particular phone user...I hope you are getting my point as i need to make changes in code.

or there is any other way of doing it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there r many similar questons on SO. Please look into my answer here in this [Dynamically populate Android ImageView with outside resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585493/dynamically-populate-android-imageview-with-outside-resources/8585638#8585638)

Comment: can i add iamges from remote server to loacal sqlite and use them as resources , without updating .apk file, i mean images should come from lcal database randomly, as they are added.

Comment: u can even use directly from server with out saving in database

Comment: actually i want some train images only available to user if he scored a certain number of poitns, so i want to update my local db for those images, but the thing is am making an object using these images and what i want is images should come randomely from DB, my question is what field i should use to get random images

Comment: use java.Math.random() to get random image from database

Comment: this java function will generate a random number, with in a certain range we specify, and if suppose we store images by id, than id might not be with in that range

Comment: @Romi but no. of images are limited

Comment: save the ids in an array and give the element of the array using a random variable(index of array)

Comment: yes exactly images are limited, suppose i have 10 images, id from 1 to 10, and generated random num is 54, than??

Comment: i am asking u to generate random variable btw 1 to 10. and match the related id

Comment: for eg. this is array {R.id.image1,R.id.image2,...} so if the random variable is 2 then image is R.id.image2... got it?

Comment: yes that i understand, but some times images may be more than ten nd some time less than 10

Comment: yea but if u keep them in an array... u should be able to know the lengh of array.. so keep the range of random number to that length

Answer (score -1):

I think the apk cant be updated once it is installed, you can have something like a free version and pro version as per the below question on SO:

[Maintain pro and free version in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887105/maintain-pro-and-free-version-in-android)

Try this:

http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Loading_images_from_a_remote_server

Comment: dont think @Romi is looking for this