# How to Install the app twice without interference in android?

Tags: android, installation, android-manifest

I have an Android app (let's called X), I want to create a second app X2 but based on the other app. So I changed the manifest application name property to X2 also I changed the package name...but still when I install X2, app X is erased!

What properties should I change so I can install the two app independently on one devices. I'm working on eclispe.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.app1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

after change.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.app2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name2"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: +1 It's legitimate question.

Comment: That's strange. Android should let you install both apps aside if the package name differs. Can you please post (the beginning of) both manifest files?

Comment: I changed the application name and label in the manifest but this had no effect! The application after install has the same old name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it worked on other device with more recent platform ! Anyway the proper response will be you just have to change the name and the package of the application.

**EDIT 1:** Now if you are using Android Studio use applicationIdSuffix to have one app for each flavor.

```
debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
```

Read more here [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)

Comment: Ya i changed the package and name of the application but still it gives a error app not installed.'

Comment: If you are using AndroidStudio check @Arpit Srivastava response.

Answer (score 3):

also change the `package` name in `gradle` script `build.gradle` module it will work

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.me.mesurvey" //put your package name here//
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed such tool because client wanted to be able use beta and release version of the app in the same time. 
I am changing main namespace of the APK to achieve this using apktool.

I follow these steps:

- decompile apk using apktool **java -jar apktool.jar d -o out -f my-app.apk**
- replace **com.mainnamespace** to **com.mainnamespacebeta** in all files in out directory
- rename directory **out/smali/com/mainnamespace** to **out/smali/com/mainnamespacebeta**
- compile apk again **java -jar apktool.jar b -o ./debug.apk -f ./out**
- sign the apk with the new key using jarsigner. **jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore ./debug.apk "password" -storepass "password" -keypass "password"**

Here is the manual how to sign the apk to get key.keystore - http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

I have also created simple script for linux - https://gist.github.com/vavrecan/8596303

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Select (click on your app) the main package and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and change the package name

Step 2: Go to `build.gradle` and change the `applicationId` to the new package name as below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.main" // your new package name
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

Step 3: Clean the project

Step 4: Run the project and see it will work for sure

Happy Coding.....