# How to install one app twice on android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I use Android Studio. And debug an application on my usb device. **What can i change in my app to install a copy of it? Now it is reinstalled.** But I need two identical apps. Changing the package in the manifest does not help. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have two apps with the same package name but changing the package should work. Are you sure you changed it?

Comment: you cannot have the same app installed as duplicates, Android will always overwrite it with the latest version. that is considering if the package name was unchanged. However, ensure you have the entire package name and class names renamed. And also in the manifest as well has to match up to the renamed package/class names. Otherwise you are doing something wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840127/how-to-install-the-app-twice-without-interference-in-android?rq=1