# Build configurations in Eclipse for Android project to switch assets?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, compilation

I need a way to quickly swap the set of assets/resources built into my Android app. I am developing an application that will be used by more than one company and each wants their own logo and help document included in the app. In other IDE's I could set up build configurations for each company and just pick which configuration I want to build, so for each release I would select the config for company 1 and build it, then select the configuration for company 2 and build it, etc.

I am already using conditional compilation techniques to swap version of functions in and out of the app, but I need to do the same with the resource files.

Is there a convenient way to do this or something like this in Eclipse?

Comment: ide is not build tool, you better use ant for that, and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222302/android-multiple-custom-versions-of-the-same-app and all linked questions

Comment: "ide is not build tool"... IDE is an INTEGRATED development environment. Texas Instruments proprietary IDE Code Composer Studio has built in functionality to do what I am talking about, so does Visual Studio. I expected more from Eclipse. Thanks for the link anyway, some ideas in there I might try, or just keep doing all the switching manually every release.

Comment: java world is different. INTEGRATED is key word here. Eclipse compiler is used for debug builds mainly. Production/stage/test/different configs builds built by build server using build tool, which will do configuration and run tests usually.